# Regex match for dictionary elements

Tags: python, regex

I am doing a regex pattern match for the following input, with the regex `\-\-(.*)\=(.*[\w\s\n\Z\r]*)`

```
--key_a=value1
--key_b=value2
--key_c=value3
--key_d=value4
--key_e=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nHYxCzAJBgNV--=B+AYT\AlVTM/QswCQYDVQQIDAJDQTE=RMA8GA1UEBwwIU2FuIEpvc2UxFTATBgNVBAoMDE51dGFuaXg\r\n
```

But the regex matches incorrectly when the value of key contains one or more `=` signs. I want the `key_e` as the first group and everything after first `=` and before next `--` as the second group. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`--(.*?)=(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/6JDE52/2).  Uses ungreedy matching to find everything between `--` and the first `=`, and then greedily matches everything after.

```
x = """
--key_a=value1
--key_b=value2
--key_c=value3
--key_d=value4
--key_e=valuewith======init========
"""
import re
print(re.findall(r'--(.*?)=(.*)', x))
```

Output:

```
[('key_a', 'value1'), ('key_b', 'value2'), ('key_c', 'value3'), ('key_d', 'value4'), ('key_e', 'valuewith======init========')]
```

Comment: This won't work when value of key_e contains empty lines or special characters too.